# Vulkan-hpp: cant allocate command buffers with no exceptions

Tags: c++, vulkan

1st of all I rewrote the Vulkan tutorial triangle in vulkan-hpp with unique handles. When closing the program i got the following assertion: `Assertion: m_dispatch && m_owner` Looking at the code, I found out enabling **VULKAN_HPP_NO_EXCEPTIONS** would fix it but now I get this error:

> vk::UniqueHandle<vk::CommandBuffer,vk::DispatchLoaderStatic> &vk::UniqueHandle<vk::CommandBuffer,vk::DispatchLoaderStatic>::operator =(const vk::UniqueHandle<vk::CommandBuffer,vk::DispatchLoaderStatic> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function

Here's my code:

```
std::tie(res, commandBuffers) = device->allocateCommandBuffersUnique(allocInfo);
```

What is the proper way to use?

```
device->allocateCommandBuffersUnique();
```

Comment: It's unique object. Try `std::move`. Or `auto cmdbuffs = device->allocateCommandBuffersUnique(allocInfo);`. That should be a move constructor.

Comment: can you be more precise? because I get and error when doing cmdbuffsf = device->allocateCommand... So how can use std::move with this?

Comment: `ResultValue` is a struct, not a tuple, so I doubt `std::tie` would work at all.

Comment: ok so what would be the correct way of using std::move?

Comment: I avoid using `vulkan.hpp` exactly for this nonsense. Perhaps best to stick to the [samples](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Hpp/blob/master/RAII_Samples/04_InitCommandBuffer/04_InitCommandBuffer.cpp), though they use bit different style. Anyway, I think move construction should work : `auto cmdbuffs = device->allocateCommandBuffersUnique(allocInfo);`. Move asignment might need explicit hint: `cmdbuffs = std::move(device->allocateCommandBuffersUnique(allocInfo) );`. Note that I have not tested these; some experimentation needed there and Vulkan-Hpp documentation is bit lacking.

Comment: ok I'll try thank's for helping.

Comment: Yea, sorry. I am not sure myself, but no one else seem to be answering this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vulkan/vulkan.hpp>

int main() try{
    const auto instance = vk::createInstanceUnique( {} );
    const auto physical_devices = instance->enumeratePhysicalDevices();

    const uint32_t q_family = 0;
    const uint32_t q_count = 1;
    const float q_prio[] = {1.0f};
    const vk::DeviceQueueCreateInfo queue_info( vk::DeviceQueueCreateFlags(), q_family, q_count, q_prio );
    const vk::DeviceCreateInfo device_info( vk::DeviceCreateFlags(), 1, &queue_info );
    const auto device = physical_devices[0].createDeviceUnique( device_info );

    const vk::CommandPoolCreateInfo cmd_pool_info( vk::CommandPoolCreateFlags(), q_family );
    const auto command_pool = device->createCommandPoolUnique( cmd_pool_info );

    const vk::CommandBufferAllocateInfo alloc_info( command_pool.get(), vk::CommandBufferLevel::ePrimary, 1 );
    const auto cmd_buffers = device->allocateCommandBuffersUnique( alloc_info );
}
catch ( ... ){
    std::cout << "error\n";
}
```

In the `VULKAN_HPP_NO_EXCEPTIONS` environment, results are just `struct`s of `value` and `result`. So:

```
    const vk::CommandBufferAllocateInfo alloc_info( command_pool.value.get(), vk::CommandBufferLevel::ePrimary, 1 );
    const auto cmd_buffers = device.value->allocateCommandBuffersUnique( alloc_info );
    if( cmd_buffers.result != vk::Result::eSuccess ) panic();
```

If you wanted to use `std::tie`, normally this should work:

```
vk::Result res;
vk::UniqueInstance instance;
std::tie(res, instance) = vk::createInstanceUnique( {} ).asTuple();
```

but there seem to be some problem with it for `allocateCommandBuffersUnique` (and possibly all `std::vector` types). I have gone ahead and reported it at [Vulkan-Hpp](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Hpp/issues/928) repo.

Though if you have access to C++17, then *structured binding* seems to work:

```
    const vk::CommandBufferAllocateInfo alloc_info( command_pool.value.get(), vk::CommandBufferLevel::ePrimary, 1 );
    auto [res, cmd_buffers] = device.value->allocateCommandBuffersUnique( alloc_info );
    if( res != vk::Result::eSuccess ) panic();
```

---

There is some recent [style change](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Hpp/blob/036e5002e0dae8d164167a9fd2fbaf3fe031879a/RAII_Samples/04_InitCommandBuffer/04_InitCommandBuffer.cpp#L50) at Vulkan-Hpp. They now suggest using `vulkan_raii.hpp` instead, though it has not yet bubbled to the Vulkan SDK. To get to the official samples using `Create*Unique` you have to go to an [older version of the repo](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Hpp/blob/8dc12ba9634e50c5b09b93e7bfd872c4e7e38092/samples/04_InitCommandBuffer/04_InitCommandBuffer.cpp).

Comment: I am using LunarG's SDK and vulkan_raii is not disponible yet. Guess I'll wait anyway thank's!